# order a capped chart with fake group does not work in dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dc.js, crossfilter

I am trying to use the `cap` function for the `rowChart` in `dc.js`. I can't get the group to use the correct ordering when rendering the graph though.
I have used the "fake group" methode found [here](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/wiki/FAQ#fake-groups).

Here is my `HTML` code :

```
<button id="btGO" type="button">GO</button>
<div id="chart-row-pnlperb4"></div>
```

And the `javascript` code :

```
var thecross;
var numSort = function(a,b) {return (a-b);};
var dim;
var group;

function go() {
    thecross = crossfilter(
        [
            {key:"a",value1:3,value2:-10},
            {key:"b",value1:3,value2:11},
            {key:"c",value1:3,value2:-12},
            {key:"d",value1:3,value2:5},
            {key:"e",value1:3,value2:3},
            {key:"f",value1:3,value2:15},
            {key:"g",value1:3,value2:-8},
            {key:"h",value1:3,value2:6},
            {key:"i",value1:3,value2:-4},
            {key:"j",value1:3,value2:12},
            {key:"k",value1:3,value2:7},
            {key:"l",value1:3,value2:-6.5}
        ]
    );

    dim = thecross.dimension(function(d) {return(d.key.toUpperCase());});
    mygroup =  dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return(d.value2);});

    var sort_group = function(source_group) {
        return {
            all: function () {
                return source_group.all();
            },
            top: function(n) {
                return source_group.top(Infinity).sort(function(x,y){return -numSort(Math.abs(x.value),Math.abs(y.value));}).slice(0,n);
            }
        };
    };
    var sorted_group = sort_group(mygroup);

    var pnlPerB4rowChart = dc.rowChart("#chart-row-pnlperb4");
    pnlPerB4rowChart
        .height(300)
        .width(700)
        .dimension(dim)
        .group(sorted_group)
        .valueAccessor(function(d) {
            return Math.abs(d.value);
        })
        //.ordering(numSort)
        .renderLabel(true)
        .renderTitle(false)
        .labelOffsetY(10)
        .elasticX(true)
        .rowsCap(10)
        .othersGrouper(false)
        .margins({left: 70 ,top: 10, bottom: 30, right: 50});

        dc.renderAll();
};

$(function(){
    $("#btGO").click(go)
});
```

I would like to get the top 10 bars sorted by descending absolute value of `value2` field.

I have put the code in [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/chapo/70zp0jku/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ordering in descending order by value is the default behavior. The only problem here is that you have negative values, so ordering by descending absolute value is not consistent with ordering by value:

I suggest that you simplify your data processing by taking the absolute value right away when computing the group:

```
    mygroup =  dim.group().reduceSum(function(d) {return Math.abs(d.value2);});
```

[image: aggregated and ordered by absolute value]
https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Ln960vq9/18/

Then you won't need all those other `Math.abs`.

If for some reason you can't do that, you could also specify the sort ordering value to be absolute value:

```
        .ordering(a=>-Math.abs(a.value))
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/Ln960vq9/20/

Comment: Thank you very much that's exactly what I needed. I thought `ordering` was not necessary in that case since I was already ordering in my fake group `.top()`definition.
Also I do need to sort by absolute value on the resulting values as opposed to taking absolute value for each record.

Comment: I don't think dc.js ever uses the group's ordering without sorting again. I'm not sure why that is.